# Fit a page to its content in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there any way to fit a page to its content in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

E.g. in the following PDF, I did some content editing and one text box is outside the page:

[image]

I would like to extend the size of the page so that it includes the entire text box:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing a PDF to fit to content in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/863286/resizing-a-pdf-to-fit-to-content-in-adobe-acrobat-xi-pro)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far, which I hope can be improved:

1. Increase the page's size:

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Crop the white space:

[image]