# Resizing a PDF to fit to content in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, resizing

Short version: Is it possible to resize a PDF to fit to content in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

---

Example: I have a PDF that contain an text object which is partially "outside the range", as the screenshot below illustrates (see red rectangle):

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Is it possible to resize the PDF so that the text object is fully displayed? Just like we can "Fit to drawing" a page in Microsoft Visio 2013:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is a screenshot, then it is a screenshot, and that is a raster image. If you want more, adjust the screen and shoot again, or use a good raster image processing software to invent what was not part of the screen you shot.

See also answer to [Equivalent of Microsoft Paint's eraser in Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/863159/equivalent-of-microsoft-paints-eraser-in-adobe-acrobat-pro) .

Comment: Thanks. Sure, PDF is not raster, but I was hoping it could modify the objects to imitate Microsoft Paint's resize tool. E.g. Inkscape can resize vectorial graphics.